# jQuery form validation equalTo hidden field

Tags: php, jquery, captcha, hidden-field

I am working on a form which is validated with jQuery before being submitted. One of the fields is a captcha.

The idea is very simple, the captcha is shown as an image and also stored in a hidden field. When the user enters the captcha in the input field it should be equal to the value of the hidden field. This is the jQuery code I have;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#register").validate({ 
errorElement: 'div', ignore: 'hidden',
rules: {
          password: { 
                required: true
          }, 
          password2: { 
                required: true, equalTo: "#password"
          },
          agree: {
              required: true
          },
          captcha: {
              required: true, equalTo: "#captcha2"
          }
      },
messages: {
password2: "Please repeat the same password",
captcha: "The captcha you entered is wrong",
agree: "You have to be at least 16 years old and agree to the terms of service" 
}
});
});
</script>
```

The html code for the form is even simpler, but I will show only a part of it.

```
<p>
    <img src='/includes/captcha.php'  />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="Captcha">Captcha</label>
    <em> *</em><input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" size="25" 
   class="require"   minlength="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="captcha2" id="captcha2" 
 value="<?php echo    $_SESSION['captcha'];?>" />
```

This should work. The problem is, however, that I keep getting the error that I set in the jQuery code, "The captcha you entered is wrong".
Can anyone tell me why the code is not working?

BTW, I checked the value of the hidden field and it is the same as the captcha, so that works

UPDATE: 
Ok, here is something weird. When I echo the session['captcha'] I get a different value than the value in the hidden field. I get the previous captcha when I echo it. So let's say the captcha value is abc. When I refresh the captcha+hidden field change into def. But when I echo session['captcha'] I still get abc.

Comment: Did you session start on the top of your page?

Comment: Not sure but I think session is playing game somewhere. Try to debug &  check/console both hidden captcha & your text box values in your validate function.

Comment: Yes, the session is set and the value of the hidden field is the same as the captcha.

Comment: Try to give any static value to hidden field & not by session & test if it's working ?

Comment: Yes, giving a static value works.

Comment: Have you checked the type you get from the Session?

Comment: Ok, here is something weird. When I echo the session['captcha'] I get a different value than the value in the hidden field. I get the previous captcha when I echo it.

So let's say the captcha value is abc. When I refresh the captcha+hidden field change into def. But when I echo session['captcha']  I still get abc.